Providing strings for functions without quotes in C
So, I know this is not the best way to start a question-- I am guessing the answer already is 'no'.
But I will give it a shot anyways in case someone happens to know some 'black magic' that could be applied.
I am trying to design a function in C that basically takes a string as input, and then is parsed to get the relevant data out of it.
In this case, that function is 'Tensor', so you can do something like the following:
a = Tensor("[[1,2], [3,4]]")

Or
b = Tensor("[1, 2, 3, 4]")

Or
c = Tensor("[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]")

Basically any reasonable combination, but the code into the function is being processed as a string.
Yet, I am wondering if there is any way I can process this, but be able to drop the 'outer quotes' of the string, so it would be a bit more like using Python. (It just isn't 'elegant' in the current state)
Or from the first example, what I'd like is:
a = Tensor([[1,2], [3,4]])

Even if I had to inject a bit of assembly code to do this, that would be 'okay'.
Just didn't know if anyone had any 'wild ideas' on this topic.
But I have no idea how to do this.

What is your objection to using "string"?

You might be able to do it if Tensor is a macro, it can stringify its argument.

Use C99 compound literals: a = Tensor((int [2][2]){{1, 2}, {3, 4}});

It is possible to do something kind of close to what you want, but a lot of it depends on how you store your tensor data and what structure(s) you wish to employ to populate it. You are probably just fine using strings... (Honestly, being tricky with syntax like this is easier in C++)

@Dúthomhas yes, I imagine with C++ it is easier, language is not of my choosing, it is an open source project.

Could you add a bit details, what problem can be solved by this approach? That code will always confuse readers and IMHO look very "wrong".

@Gerhardh it is just a data structure-- All the fun stuff happens on the backend.

That does not answer what problem you can solve by stripping the quotes from your string literal.

#define Tensor(...) Tensor(#__VA_ARGS__)

Macro replacement in C is not recursive, so Tensor will not be macro-processed again after the first replacement.
Declare and define the Tensor function before defining this macro or use #undef to remove the macro before any declaration or definition of the function (and redefine the macro afterward if necessary).

Thanks, as you and another have suggested, let me look up 'macros'. I've not used them before and the code I'm building on is not mine, so lemme see if I can make it work. Again, the actual 'processing' the string part is working fine, I'm just hoping to dump the quotes.

@Nevermnd Playing with syntax can be fun, but it is almost always a side quest. For commercial code, if what you have is working and the profiler is not listing it as one of your top three problems — then you are just wasting time for a minor prettiness.

IMO it is a bad idea to name the function and the macro the same. Name the macro TENSOR and the function tensor. That way, a programmer with more C exposure can call the function directly with quotes. I used to be a fan of using fancy macros to make new language syntax, but as I've grown older I only do it if it brings significant added value. This doesn't. The problem is that there are thousands of programmers who know C; there will only be one programmer who knows your modified language.

Thanks for the feedback guys. The project is actually open source that I am trying to contribute to, but it has also thus far served as a good excuse for me to both ask and test out 'what is possible' and learn new things. For example, I got to teach myself CUDA. Similarly here-- it is not a 'hard fast' requirement... But I just didn't know if it could be done.

@StreveFord While it is true that making macros for the sake of re-defining the C language is a horrible idea, writing a wrapper macro around a function with the same name is super common practice - the C standard lib does this all over the place. The key in such situations is that the caller shouldn't need to know or care if they are calling a function or a macro.

I will try it today, but I think what Eric said should work, so I am giving him answer credit. Thank you all.
